# How can I write a Broadcast Receiver that will be invoked when user clicks on any application icon?

Tags: android

How can I write a Broadcast Receiver that will be invoked when user clicks on any application icon?

I tried by writing:

```
<receiver android:name = "myreceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN"> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

But it is not called.

I tried, 
by using `Packagemanager` I will get `ApplicationInfo`. From that I can know all the application starting activity name and package names. I thought I can use them to registerReceiver
and my receiver will listen by its launching activity and package name. 
But I strucked. I am unable to do that. I think I lost the way.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, there is just too much room for abuse.  What are you trying to do that you would need to be notified anytime someone launched an application?

Comment: I actually was also looking for similar functionality to log user activity (apps opening, mainly, not keypress/browser activity, etc)

Comment: i would like to keep lock to application.when ever user tries to start the application i.e clicks on application icon my receiver has to leason to it and a dialog box will opened if user gives correct details then application will unlocked and application will start..

now tell me am i in right way to achieve my task..
please guide me..
thanks in advance..

Comment: What I'm telling you is that I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want.  You can (of course) tell when apps that you have written, but I don't think the OS will allow people to hook into the launch of all apps.

Comment: if it is our application we can register a broadcastreceiver with our own action and we can achive it right?
thanks for your clarification caseyB..
any way it is very  bad news for me..

Comment: It is possible to do so (see my answer below), and it can be used for many other things besides evil purposes: hiding the keyboard, counting click events, muting sounds, playing sounds..... This post is 5 yrs old but anyways...

Answer (score 0):

Use this technique:

```
//implement onClickListener on your class

Class blabla extends Activity implements onClickListener{
...
...
}

//this will force you to override the onClick method on your activity or //fragment
@override
void onClick(View V){
sendBroadcast(new Intent("clickSomewhere!"));
//Put here more actions you want to do when anything is touched/clicked
}
```

Basically this is it. Anytime you press a button the Broadcast will be sent. Your Broadcast receiver, could be coded in some other place, listening to incoming broadcasts. If you need more code of the broadcast sending side, or the broadcast receiving side let me know.